# Bypass initializer in specs

Tags: ruby, rspec, bdd, stub

I have the following method to create a new Connection object. It will open a serial port. Note that it will fail when the port does not exist.

```
class Connection
 def initialize(port)
   begin
      @serial = SerialPort.new(port, 9600, 8, 1, SerialPort::NONE)
    rescue
      exit(1)
    end
  end

  def send_command
    @serial.write "Something"
  end
end
```

I wrote a RSpec spec for this method, so far so good. Now, I would like to spec the next method, "send_command".

The problem is I can not call `Connection.new("/some/port")` in this spec as it will fail (the port does not exist). How can I bypass the creation method without stubbing the new method? If I understand correctly I am not allowed to stub or mock the class I'm testing, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass in a SerialPort object instead of a port number (dependency injection), or a factory object that has a create method that returns a SerialPort object (abstract factory pattern). The tests could then pass in a fake/mock/dummy SerialPort or SerialPort factory.

But maybe that is the C++ programmer in me talking, gnab's advice seems to be more Rubyish...

Comment: Yes, you are right about the dependency injection and that's exactly why it's more difficult to test. I will extract the SerialPort class and pass it as a parameter. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could stub the `new` and `write` methods of the `SerialPort` class.

Comment: Thanks gnab, the thing that's bothering me is that I have to do it in each describe block. I was wondering if it would be acceptable to stub the Connection.new method or is that stubbing a method of the class I'm testing and as such unacceptable?

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat hacky, but rather than calling `Connection.new`, you could call `Connection.allocate`. This creates an object without calling `initialize`.